# How to add Slick Slider in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, requirejs, slider, magento2.2.6

I have done the following to add slick slider autoplay in magento 2.. 
 In my custom module requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
       '*': {
           slick: 'xxx_yyy/js/slick.min',
           slickSlider: 'xxx_yyy/js/slick-slider'
       }
   },
   shim: {
        slick: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
   },
};
```

My slick-slider.js for slider autoplay is

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'slick'
], function ($) {
    // $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".slider-gallery").slick({
            autoplay: true,
            dots: true,
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 500,
                settings: {
                    dots: false,
                    arrows: false,
                    infinite: false,
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 2
                }
            }]

        });
    // });
});
```

and i have initiated slick-slider.js in my template as

```
 <div class="slider" data-mage-init='{"slickSlider":{}}'>
            <div class="slide">
                <h1>slide 1</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <h1>slide 2</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
              <h1>slide 3</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
               <h1>slide 4</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
               <h1>slide 5</h1>
            </div>
</div>
```

but it is not working. Can anyone tell me how to add slick slider in magento 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct your step 2 make as below, Keep requirejs-config.js file in root of your theme instead of web folder.

Create requirejs-config.js file in

```
app/design/frontend/_YOUR_VENDOR_/_YOUR_THEME_/
```

with the following code in requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        slick:        'js/slick'
    },
    shim: {
        slick: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Shouldn't add it in my custom module?

Comment: Okay so u can check first view page source your slick slider javasscript call or not?

Comment: Ya i tried...But its not working.....

Comment: Please check in your js

Comment: checked page source. My js is getting called. slick classes are getting added to div in template.. But autoplay slider is not working...

Comment: Maybe its because div class = slider but js is called on 'slider-gallery' ? Try making sure you are calling the js on the appropriate class.